# Reducing boilerplate when decorating methods

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a large number of classes which are used to decorate a few specific methods.

Is there a clean way to reduce the amount of boilerplate code (mainly all the constructor parameters and members to hold them) that needs to be added to each of these classes?  Or, even better, is there a nicer way to do this?

I can't use virtual methods, and can only use the subset of c++11 features supported by gcc 4.6 and vs2010.

I believe c++11 inheriting constructors would help here, but neither compiler supports them and I'm not aware of a workaround.

Here's an example of what these classes currently look like:

```
template<class Underlying, class T1>
struct A : Base<A<Underlying, T1> >
{
    typedef AImpl<decltype(declval<Underlying>().foo()), T1> impl;
    A(Underlying u, T1 t1) :
        u_(u),
        t1_(t1)
    {}

    impl foo() const { return impl(u_.foo(), t1_); }
    impl bar() const { return impl(u_.bar(), t1_); }

    const Underlying u_;
    T1 t1_;
};


template<class Underlying, class T1, class T2>
struct B : Base<B<Underlying, T1, T2> >
{
    typedef BImpl<decltype(declval<Underlying>().bar()), T1, T2> impl;
    B(Underlying u, T1 t1, T2 t2) :
        u_(u),
        t1_(t1),
        t2_(t2)
    {}

    impl foo() const { return impl(u_.bar(), 999, t2_); }
    impl bar() const { return impl(u_.foo(), t1_, t2_); }

    const Underlying u_;
    T1 t1_;
    T2 t2;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use variadic templates in GCC 4.6.

```
template<class Underlying, class... T>
struct B : Base<B<Underlying, T...>>
{
    typedef BImpl<decltype(declval<Underlying>().bar()), T...> impl;

    template<typename V...>
    B(Underlying u, V... v) :
        u_(u),
        t_(std::forward<V>(v)...)
    {}

    impl foo() const { return impl(u_.bar(), 999, std::get<1>(t_)); } // Not sure what the 999 is?
    impl bar() const { return impl(u_.foo(), std::get<0>(t_), std::get<1>(t_)); }

    const Underlying u_;
    std::tuple<T...> t_;
};
```

Comment: I think the use of `forward` might be slightly incorrect (inefficient at least) here. By default, any use of `forward` should be in a method call with deduced parameter types. That means `template<class... V> B(Underlying u, V&&... t) : u_(u),
        t_(std::forward<V>(t)...)
{}` . Three things: 1) The function itself should be a template. 2) The args should be taken as `U&&...`, and `forward` shuld be used. The current code will *copy* the parameters into `B` and then it might *move* them into the base class. Ideally, you want zero copies and instead have moves all the way, when possible.

Comment: Two things, get is not a member of tuple in the standard implementation (it is in Boost), and the use of forward is incorrect in your constructor.  Should be `template<class... V> B(Underlying u, V&&... v) : u_(u), t_(std::forward<V>(v)...) {}`.

Answer (score 1):

If it needs to work in vs2010, then your best bet is [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/libs/preprocessor).  It is not as robust as variadic templates in that it has a maximum recursion depth of 3 and a maximum iteration count of 256, but it works in every compiler with or without C++11 support.  It isn't completely clear what you are trying to do with those examples, but if you are just trying to decorate functions, I use the following (utilizes C++11 for perfect forwarding with Boost.Preprocessor instead of variadic templates):

```
#define FORWARD(z, n, data) \
    ::std::forward<BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 0, data), n)> \
    (BOOST_PP_CAT(BOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 1, data), n)) \
    /**/

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// template<class R, class... A>
// ::std::function<R(A...)> decorate(::std::function<R(A...)> const& func)
// {
//     return [func](A&&... a) -> R
//     {
//         /* DECORATOR STUFF */
//         return func(::std::forward<A>(a)...);
//     };
// }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
#define MACRO(z, n, _) \
    template<class R BOOST_PP_ENUM_TRAILING_PARAMS_Z(z, n, class A)> \
    ::std::function<R(BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS_Z(z, n, a)> \
        decorate(::std::function<R(BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS_Z(z, n, A))> const& func) \
    { \
        return [func](BOOST_PP_ENUM_BINARY_PARAMS_Z(z, n, A, &&a)) -> R \
        { \
            /* DECORATOR STUFF */ \
            return func(BOOST_PP_ENUM_ ## z(n, FORWARD, (A, a))); \
        }; \
    } \
    /**/

BOOST_PP_REPEAT(10, MACRO, ~)

#undef MACRO
#undef FORWARD
```

If you are just trying to bind up function arguments, then [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) is what you are looking for.  Note that you can do any of this with just [lambdas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C.2B.2B), but the decorator functions can be used to decorate multiple functions (where as lambdas are of course one offs) and bind can be a little more concise for binding arguments (however, the lambda equivalent is sometimes more readable).